# Drop all rows in Pandas DataFrame where value is NOT NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I can remove all rows with nan in a column with this line:

```
df2 = df.dropna(subset=['columnA'])
```

How do I remove all rows that have values **other than** NaN?

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you need to perform an operation only on a subset of rows, there are other ways to do that. You don't have to drop rows, do the operations, and concatenate back ;p Why don't you post what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do `drop`

```
df2 = df.dropna(subset=['columnA'])
df1 = df.drop(df2.index)
```

Comment: or in one line, to avoid defining new variables, `df.drop(df.dropna(subset=['columnA']).index)`

Answer (score 3):

```
df.loc[lambda x:x.columnA.isnull()]
```

Comment: Please add explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the most logical and simple solution:

```
df = df[df['columnA'].isnull()]
```

Comment: Pretty similar to my Jan 22, 2020 answer. Technically @BENY is answering the questioning as it was phrased, to specifically drop rows.

Comment: @CactusPhilosopher you are right, this is almost the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing something in the question.

Just keep the rows where value is equal to `np.nan`

As @rafaelc pointed out `np.nan == np.nan` is `false`.

And I was completely wrong I am leaving the answer here just to keep the comments here for anyone who comes looking.

Changing based on that.

```
df2 = df[df['ColumnA'] != np.nan]   # WRONG ANSWER
df1 = df[~(df['ColumnA'] != np.nan)] #WRONG ANSWER

# perform function on df1  # WRONG ANSWER

df_f = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

Comment: Good idea, but won't work ;p Try to do `np.nan == np.nan` to check for youself! Can't compare `nans` with `==`

Comment: @rafaelc learned something again. I changed the answer based on your input. If I remember correctly check `!=` works.

Comment: Similarly, `!=` won't work because `np.nan != np.nan` is `True` haha ;p If you want to find `nans`, use `pd.isnull`. For example, `pd.isnull(df['ColumnA'])` yields the results you are looking for !